# ControlFactory use for cloning a control

Tags: c#, .net

I want to clone all the controls in an existing tab. I got the following after some research:

```
foreach (Control c in this.tabCard1.Controls)
{
    // clone control 
    Control ctrl = ControlFactory.CloneCtrl(c);
}
```

However, I get error:

> "CS0103: - The name ControlFactory does not exist in the current
>   context"

Can anyone help or give another coding solution for cloning the controls easily?
I am using .NET framework 3.5

Comment: Well, what is `ControlFactory`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: perhaps [this sharepoint class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.retail.sharepoint.web.controls.controlfactory.aspx). However, there is no `CloneCtrl` method.

Comment: @peter schneider Thanks for fixing my title edit. I've got a crappy logitech wireless keyboard that lags terribly. I obviously hit the backspace key too many times.

Comment: The Sharepoint ControlFactory class is only for creating HTML controls See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.retail.sharepoint.web.controls.controlfactory_methods.aspx) `public static HtmlButton CreateButton` - You will have to clone the controls all relevant properties yourself, I'm afraid. Or try Google..

Comment: Sorry about that. ControlFactory has been taken from source code in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12976/How-to-Clone-Serialize-Copy-Paste-a-Windows-Forms. This does the job of cloning all controls.

Answer (score 1):

The `X does not exist in the current context` error is typically encountered in scenarios where your class does not contain a `using` statement for the appropriate namespace.

If your project has the necessary reference added, this can be resolved in Visual Studio by placing the cursor on the `ControlFactory` text and pressing `Ctrl + .` - this should give the option of fully qualifying the reference to your `ControlFactory` class or of adding a `using` statement.  If the correct reference does not exist on the project you won't get these options.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a new problem :) I see that the controls are cloned but they don't appear in the new tab.

Comment: This is my updated code:     this.tabSettings.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

            // iterate through each control and clone it
            foreach (Control c in tabCard1.Controls)
            {
                // clone control (this references the code project download ControlFactory.cs)
                Control ctrl = ControlFactory.CloneCtrl(c);
                // set bounds to size and position
                ctrl.SetBounds(c.Bounds.X, c.Bounds.Y, c.Bounds.Width, c.Bounds.Height);
                // now add it to the new tab
                myTabPage.Controls.Add(ctrl);

            }

Comment: You should create a new question for this issue. For one thing it's a real pain to read un-formatted code in comments but more importantly, if/when your new issue is resolved, it is unlikely to be of use to people who might be seeking an answer to a similar problem, hidden as it is under the title _ControlFactory use for cloning a control_.